# Windows XP guest VM using max CPU on guest Lubuntu VM

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, virtual-machine

When I try to run a Windows XP VM on my Lubuntu guest VM, it runs extremely slowly and is often unresponsive. When I checked task manager to see what was causing it, I saw that the CPU was working at 100% power due to a vital process called "services.exe". I've already checked to see if the Lubuntu VM was also unresponsive, but it seems to work relatively fine. The especially confusing part is that the CPU usage will occasionally drop to a low of 10-30%, and the computer will run fine again for a minute before spiking back up to 100%. I've tried reinstalling the nested XP vm with 2 cores but all the vm did was start using both at 100%. I am running VirtualBox version 7.02 and the host for the Lubuntu VM is a Windows 10. Any suggestions on what to do next would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're running a VM *inside* another VM? One *would* expect that to be slow.

Comment: I was trying to see if I could have a nested VM work well in a Linux VM, just for later reference. I wouldn't expect Windows XP to be this slow, since it demands very few resources from today's computers.

Comment: XP might not require a lot of resources, but check Task Manager to see how much the VM uses.

Comment: Is nested hardware virtualization available within the Lubuntu VM? Were VBox 'Guest Additions' installed to XP? I'm sure this is not a matter of "resources needed for XP"; it's VBox having difficulties emulating something specific.

Comment: Linux VM, just for later reference.   .....    Try running the machine non-nested.  Reason:  to determine if the issue is your XP machine or if it is the nesting issue.

Comment: I ran the XP machine non-nested and it works without a problem, I checked gnome-system-monitor to see how many resources the machine used, and it didn't take too much processing power away from the main guest. I also decided to reinstall guest additions on my nested VM and it seemed to work better than before, but it still had spikes where it used large amounts of CPU power.